# Json Object Array:replacing 'key' names with their values to avoid same key name and easy retrieval

Tags: node.js, json, arrayobject

I have an array of json object like this:

```
[
    {
        "entity": "clientModal",
        "value": "MacBook"
    },
    {
        "entity": "siteName",
        "value": "abde"
    },
    {
        "entity": "clientModal",
        "value": "MacBook"
    },
    {
        "entity": "siteName",
        "value": "abcd"
    },
    {
        "entity": "clientName",
        "value": "ghe-1202m"
    },
    {
        "entity": "timePeriod",
        "value": "week"
    },
    {
        "entity": "clientName",
        "value": "ghe-1202m"
    },
    {
        "entity": "timePeriod",
        "value": "week"
    },
    {
        "entity": "clientName",
        "value": "ghe-1202m"
    },
    {
        "entity": "clientName",
        "value": "ppphone"
    },
    {
        "entity": "clientName",
        "value": "pppiphone"
    }
]
```

I want that key 'entity' should be replaced by its value everywhere and the key'value' must be inside it.
Like this:

[
       {
        "clientName":
          {
            "value":"ppiphone"
          }
        }
]

I tried evreything but still not find anything.

Answer (score 1):

You need to map the array and create a new object wherein the `entity` value will serve as the name of the key.

```js
const arrays = [
    {
        "entity": "clientModal",
        "value": "MacBook"
    },
    {
        "entity": "siteName",
        "value": "abde"
    },
    {
        "entity": "clientModal",
        "value": "MacBook"
    },
    {
        "entity": "siteName",
        "value": "abcd"
    },
    {
        "entity": "clientName",
        "value": "ghe-1202m"
    },
    {
        "entity": "timePeriod",
        "value": "week"
    },
    {
        "entity": "clientName",
        "value": "ghe-1202m"
    },
    {
        "entity": "timePeriod",
        "value": "week"
    },
    {
        "entity": "clientName",
        "value": "ghe-1202m"
    },
    {
        "entity": "clientName",
        "value": "ppphone"
    },
    {
        "entity": "clientName",
        "value": "pppiphone"
    }
];

const mappedArray = arrays.map(arr => ({
   [arr.entity]: {
     value: arr.value
   }
}));

console.log(mappedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try something without create new array for output. Just modify existing:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
    arrays[i] = {
        [arrays[i].entity]: {
            value: arrays[i].value
        }
    }
}

console.log(arrays)
```

Answer (score -1):

Followed a much basic approach of looping.

```js
var a = [
    {
        "entity": "clientModal",
        "value": "MacBook"
    },
    {
        "entity": "siteName",
        "value": "abde"
    },
    {
        "entity": "clientModal",
        "value": "MacBook"
    }
];
var finalArray = []
for(let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    let s =`{ "${a[i].entity}": { "value": "${a[i].value}" } }`;
    finalArray.push(JSON.parse(s));
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(finalArray));
```

### Output:

```
[{"clientModal":{"value":"MacBook"}},{"siteName":{"value":"abde"}},{"clientModal":{"value":"MacBook"}}]
```